# Доступ за пределами размера массива

Tags: c++

Изучаю основные возможности С++ и вот такой код :

```
int mas[12];

mas[15]=15;
cout<<"15 element = "<<mas[15]<<"\n";
```

по непонятным мне причинам работает. Ведь это выход за границы массива ?

Comment: просто повезло.

Comment: c++ не проверяет индекс для массива. Он просто отсчитал 56 (14*sizeof(int)) байт и записал по этому адресу. А там скорее всего доступная память и никому не мешает (пока).

Comment: А за что минусы? Хороший новичковый вопрос, на понимание сути языка.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C++ — небезопасный язык.

Правила языка говорят, что нельзя выходить за границы выделенной памяти. Ответственность за выполнение правил возлагается на вас, программиста. C++, в отличие от безопасных языков, не проверяет, следуете ли вы правилам, поэтому вы не получите ошибку непосредственно в этой точке.

Но раз вы нарушили правила, может случиться любая неприятность. Стандарт подчёркивает, что при нарушении вами правил **все** гарантии языка снимаются.

При чтении за границами массива, если вам повезёт, и память по смещению в 15 размеров элемента от начала массива доступна, и не содержит ничего плохого (на интеловской архитектуре «плохого» не бывает, но на других [вполне](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040119-00/?p=41003/)) и если оптимизатор не очень умный, вы просто прочитаете какое-то непонятное значение.

В случае, если вам повезёт меньше, программа просто упадёт.

А в совсем плохом случае программа начнёт вести себя странно, причём в каком-то далёком, не связанном с этой точкой месте.

При записи всё ещё хуже, по этому адресу может случайно оказаться какая-нибудь важная структура данных (например, это может быть адрес возврата из текущей функции), и вы перезапишете его каким-то непонятным значением по принципу «на кого бог пошлёт».

Просто не делайте так, C++ доверяет вам.

Comment: Ещё бы добавил, что в С++ как и в Си массив по сути - это указатель на первый элемент массива. А в этих языках работает так называемая арифметика указателей, когда вы можете прибавлять/убавлять к текущему адресу некоторое смещение и получать новый адрес. Но вот что под ним будет - это уже вопрос. Из хорошего - это в численных методах часто используется для эмуляции многомерных массивов, либо для массивов, начинающихся не с нуля. Из плохого - как уже писали негарантируемое поведение, либо вектор атаки для взлома приложения - переписывание стэка вызовов.